# Buscar el numero de columna de un array 2d de tipo char que contiene cada una de las letras de una palabra dada en JAVA

Tags: java, array-bidimensional, iteradores

Necesito que: Al ingresar una palabra cualquiera se busque cada una de las letras que componen la palabra dentro de una matriz tipo char que contiene todas las letras del abedario en este formato (7 filas y 4 columnas)

```
char [][] lista =           {{'a','b','c','d'},
                             {'e','f','g','h'},
                             {'i','j','k','l'},
                             {'m','n','ñ','o'},
                             {'p','q','r','s'},
                             {'t','u','v','w'},
                             {'x','y','z','-'}};
```

Y que el numero de columna en la que se encuentra cada letra se sume y se muestre la suma.

Por ejemplo, si la palabra es "Hola", la letra "H" está en columna 4,la letra "O" está en columna 4, la letra "L" está en columna 4 y la letra "A" está en la columna 1 y que se muestre que el total de la suma es 13.

```
        String cad = "hola";
        
        char [][] lista =   {{'a','b','c','d'},
                             {'e','f','g','h'},
                             {'i','j','k','l'},
                             {'m','n','ñ','o'},
                             {'p','q','r','s'},
                             {'t','u','v','w'},
                             {'x','y','z','-'}};

        
        char[] texto = cad.toCharArray();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < lista[0].length; i++){ 
            for(int j = 0; j < lista.length; j++){ 

        }
    }
```

He estado haciendo las iteraciones para filas y columnas, mi mayor problema es que no sé como buscar cada uno de los elementos de un vector dentro de una matriz

PD: Soy nuevo en esto de Java :D

Comment: bueno, y que has intentado. Te recomiendo leer [ask], toda pregunta debe tener un [example], demostrando un poco de esfuerzo para resolver el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1ero necesitaras un for que recorra cada letra de la palabra un
2do un for que recorra las 7 filas y un
3er for que recorra las 4 columnas
te en cuenta que los indices parten de  cero, por ende le sumamos 1 a la columna encontrada `j+1`

```
 //variable que ira sumando el numero de la columna donde se encuentre la letra a buscar
                int suma=0;
 //recorreremos la matriz buscando la columna donde esta la letra y esto se repetirá 
 //de acuerdo a la longitud de la palabra 
            
            for(int k=0;k<texto.length;k++){
                for(int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){ //filas
                    for(int j = 0; j < lista[0].length; j++){ //columnas
                      if(lista[i][j]==texto[k]){
                           suma=suma+(j+1);
                      }
                  }
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola vi tu pregunta y quise solucionarla, aquí te dejo mi resultado:

1- Primero

```java
//Puedes hacer final esta lista, debido a que nunca van a cambiar sus resultados
        final char [][] list =   {
                {'a','b','c','d'},
                {'e','f','g','h'},
                {'i','j','k','l'},
                {'m','n','ñ','o'},
                {'p','q','r','s'},
                {'t','u','v','w'},
                {'x','y','z','-'}};
```

El string que uso de prueba es "Prueba" literalmente
Como puedes ver también defino una variable para sacar el tamaño del string, esto debe de hacer así debido a que si lo sacas dentro en cada iteración del for estarás llamando al método que cuanta el string, de esta forma solo haces esto una vez

```java
        var palabra = "Prueba";
        var suma = 0;
        var tamaño = palabra.length();

        for(int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++){
            for(char[] array : list){
                var columanActual = 0;
                for(char c : array){
                    ++columanActual;
                    //toLowerCase pone toda la cadena en minuscala
                    //charAt busca el caracter en la pocicion "i" de la cadena
                    if(palabra.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == c){
                        suma += columanActual;
                        //break para terminar el for
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("El resultado a Prueba es: "+ suma );
```

En lugar de los for normales utilice for each, en esencia son los mismo ambos recorren el array, pero para mi gusto son mas legibles.

Luego el valor de las columnas las manejo con un contador que voy incrementado cuando ingresa al tercer for.

Otra cosa importante es utilizar toLowerCase debido a que java es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, y en tu matriz todos los caracteres están en minúscula.

Lo ultimo es el break, este si lo utilizas dentro de un for lo que hace es terminarlo en esa iteración, como ves lo agrego para una vez que encuentre la letra terminar la iteración e ir al siguiente carácter mas rápido (El rendimiento que da en este caso no es mucho como de 1-2 milisegundos no mas).

El resultado aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El codigo no va en imagenes, va en texto, para eso estan las herramientas al redactar la respuesta, recomiendo leer [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Yo también estoy practicando Java, lo resolví así.

Gracias por compartir ejercicios!

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Introduzca una palabra:");

String palabra = entrada.next().toLowerCase();

entrada.close();
int count = 0; // inicialización contandor

    //recorremos filas
    for(int f=0; f<7; f++)   
    {
         // recorrermos columnas
        for (int k = 0; k<4; k++) 
        {
            // recorremos letras
            for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) 
            {
                // condicion si letra es igual a la posicion 
                //dentro de la matriz

                if (palabra.charAt(i) == matriz[f][k]) 
                {
                  // sumamos la posicion de la columna en el contador, 
                 //k+1 porque si la columna es cero queremos que nos 
                 //sume 1
                    count = count + k+1; 
                    
                }

                
            }
            

        }

    }
    

    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).